# How to join lines in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I would like to ask a question about joining lines in a file on Linux.

This is a part of the file:

```
"64f94e8e-4bd2-4721-95e7-7151cfbf3eb6"|"fanel"|""|""|""|"2020-05-20 12:23:54.611000+00:00"
"d955466b-125d-42dd-a1f6-a31e1ff6889b"|"Rancher_rke_1_0_8_Linux"|""|""|"Rancher 13 images scan:
199M May 20 12:58 calico-cni.tar
54M May 20 12:58 calico-kube-controllers.tar
252M May 20 12:58 calico-node.tar
108M May 20 12:58 calico-pod2daemon-flexvol.tar
40M May 20 12:58 cluster-proportional-autoscaler.tar
40M May 20 12:58 coredns-coredns.tar
82M May 20 12:58 coreos-etcd.tar
1.5G May 20 12:58 hyperkube.tar
40M May 20 12:58 metrics-server.tar
5.0M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend.tar
488M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller.tar
737K May 20 12:58 pause.tar
129M May 20 12:58 rke-tools.tar
"|"2020-05-20 09:56:43.388000+00:00"
"853f2f8b-563b-4ea3-a465-7be4510ce66f"|"SPOT_NEWSCAN_747"|""|""|""|"2020-06-09 08:11:02.563000+00:00"
"f3d735a7-7883-48c1-91cc-28075d300d62"|"kinesis-stream-manager"|""|""|""|"2020-05-21 06:50:15.440000+00:00"
```

Line start with `"` and end with `"`, but line starting with `"d955466b` is not ending with `"` and continue to other lines.

I can find the problematic lines with `sed -n '/\"$/!p' PROJECT2.csv` but I have no idea how do join only for problematic lines.

Final result needs to be:

```
"d955466b-125d-42dd-a1f6-a31e1ff6889b"|"Rancher_rke_1_0_8_Linux"|""|""|"Rancher 13 images scan:199M May 20 12:58 calico-cni.tar54M May 20 12:58 calico-kube-controllers.tar252M May 20 12:58 calico-node.tar108M May 20 12:58 calico-pod2daemon-flexvol.tar40M May 20 12:58 cluster-proportional-autoscaler.tar40M May 20 12:58 coredns-coredns.tar82M May 20 12:58 coreos-etcd.tar1.5G May 20 12:58 hyperkube.tar40M May 20 12:58 metrics-server.tar5.0M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend.tar488M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller.tar737K May 20 12:58 pause.tar129M May 20 12:58 rke-tools.tar"|"2020-05-20 09:56:43.388000+00:00"
```

Comment: Note that it's valid for CSV fields to contain newline characters. That shouldn't be a problem if you process them with proper CSV parsers. If that file is indeed in proper CSV format, and you do indeed want to remove newline characters from csv fields, you may also need to take into accounts CSV records that contain escaped double quotes (generally represented as `""`) such as `"foo"|" blah ""blah""<newline>blah"`, where the *newline* is in that case part of the second field even though it follows a `"`.

Comment: From the point of the CSV format, there is no issue with your data. Having newlines embedded in a quoted field is totally valid.  A CSV parser would have no issues reading the data. How are you planning to parse the data in that field once you have removed the newlines or replaced them with spaces?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the output of `cat -v file` so we can see where any CRs are.

Answer (score 2):

Try counting the double quotes and adding lines until count is even:

```
awk '{while (gsub(/"/, "&")%2) {getline X; $0 = $0 X}} 1' file
```

Comment: Neat! Although I suspect this is a csv file and the csv format allows nested `"`, so there might be a `"` inside another field. In that case, your approach would fail since the number of quotes would be odd.

Comment: @terdon per [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) a `"` within a field is escaped by preceding it with a second `"` so then it's still an even number as a field looks like `"my ""good"" day"`. Excel, the other defacto "standard" for CSVs,  behaves the same way when creating CSVs. I hear there may be some other CSVs out there where `"` can be escaped with ```\``` instead but I've never actually come across one.

Comment: Oooh! Thanks, @EdMorton, I'd never seen the specs before. I just had this vague notion that `"` are not forbidden within fields, but didn't know there were any special rules.

Answer (score 2):

Remove any newlines that are not right after a `"`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<!")\n//' file
"64f94e8e-4bd2-4721-95e7-7151cfbf3eb6"|"fanel"|""|""|""|"2020-05-20 12:23:54.611000+00:00"
"d955466b-125d-42dd-a1f6-a31e1ff6889b"|"Rancher_rke_1_0_8_Linux"|""|""|"Rancher 13 images scan:199M May 20 12:58 calico-cni.tar54M May 20 12:58 calico-kube-controllers.tar252M May 20 12:58 calico-node.tar108M May 20 12:58 calico-pod2daemon-flexvol.tar40M May 20 12:58 cluster-proportional-autoscaler.tar40M May 20 12:58 coredns-coredns.tar82M May 20 12:58 coreos-etcd.tar1.5G May 20 12:58 hyperkube.tar40M May 20 12:58 metrics-server.tar5.0M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend.tar488M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller.tar737K May 20 12:58 pause.tar129M May 20 12:58 rke-tools.tar"|"2020-05-20 09:56:43.388000+00:00"
"853f2f8b-563b-4ea3-a465-7be4510ce66f"|"SPOT_NEWSCAN_747"|""|""|""|"2020-06-09 08:11:02.563000+00:00"
"f3d735a7-7883-48c1-91cc-28075d300d62"|"kinesis-stream-manager"|""|""|""|"2020-05-21 06:50:15.440000+00:00"
```

Or

```
$ perl -pe 's/([^"])\n/$1/' file
"64f94e8e-4bd2-4721-95e7-7151cfbf3eb6"|"fanel"|""|""|""|"2020-05-20 12:23:54.611000+00:00"
"d955466b-125d-42dd-a1f6-a31e1ff6889b"|"Rancher_rke_1_0_8_Linux"|""|""|"Rancher 13 images scan:199M May 20 12:58 calico-cni.tar54M May 20 12:58 calico-kube-controllers.tar252M May 20 12:58 calico-node.tar108M May 20 12:58 calico-pod2daemon-flexvol.tar40M May 20 12:58 cluster-proportional-autoscaler.tar40M May 20 12:58 coredns-coredns.tar82M May 20 12:58 coreos-etcd.tar1.5G May 20 12:58 hyperkube.tar40M May 20 12:58 metrics-server.tar5.0M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend.tar488M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller.tar737K May 20 12:58 pause.tar129M May 20 12:58 rke-tools.tar"|"2020-05-20 09:56:43.388000+00:00"
"853f2f8b-563b-4ea3-a465-7be4510ce66f"|"SPOT_NEWSCAN_747"|""|""|""|"2020-06-09 08:11:02.563000+00:00"
"f3d735a7-7883-48c1-91cc-28075d300d62"|"kinesis-stream-manager"|""|""|""|"2020-05-21 06:50:15.440000+00:00"
```

Or, same thing with GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/([^"])\n/\1/g' file
"64f94e8e-4bd2-4721-95e7-7151cfbf3eb6"|"fanel"|""|""|""|"2020-05-20 12:23:54.611000+00:00"
"d955466b-125d-42dd-a1f6-a31e1ff6889b"|"Rancher_rke_1_0_8_Linux"|""|""|"Rancher 13 images scan:199M May 20 12:58 calico-cni.tar54M May 20 12:58 calico-kube-controllers.tar252M May 20 12:58 calico-node.tar108M May 20 12:58 calico-pod2daemon-flexvol.tar40M May 20 12:58 cluster-proportional-autoscaler.tar40M May 20 12:58 coredns-coredns.tar82M May 20 12:58 coreos-etcd.tar1.5G May 20 12:58 hyperkube.tar40M May 20 12:58 metrics-server.tar5.0M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend.tar488M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller.tar737K May 20 12:58 pause.tar129M May 20 12:58 rke-tools.tar"|"2020-05-20 09:56:43.388000+00:00"
"853f2f8b-563b-4ea3-a465-7be4510ce66f"|"SPOT_NEWSCAN_747"|""|""|""|"2020-06-09 08:11:02.563000+00:00"
"f3d735a7-7883-48c1-91cc-28075d300d62"|"kinesis-stream-manager"|""|""|""|"2020-05-21 06:50:15.440000+00:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways is to assign ORS values depending on the presence/absence of a double quote at the end of line.

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN { a[1] = ORS }
{ ORS = a[/"$/] };1' file
```

---

Another approach is to use the GNU ed editor's join command alongside line addressing:

```bsh
ed -s file <<\eof
v/"$/ .,//j
,p
Q
eof
```

---

the awk can be ported to Perl in a one-on-one manner:

```
$ perl -lpe '$\ = ($,,$/)[/"$/]' file
```

---

This is an approach using GNU sed in extended regex mode (-E)

```bsh
sed -E '
  /"$/b
  :loop
    $q;N;s/([^"])\n/\1/
  tloop
  P;D
' file
```

---

Here is another approach using the csplit utility:

```bsh
cat - file <<\eof |\
csplit -sz - '/"$/' '{*}'
"."
eof
for f in xx*; do {
  head -n 1 -
  cat - | tr -d '\n'
} < "$f"
done | sed 1d
```

---

Answer (score 1):

With standard `sed` :

```
sed '/"$/!ba;p;d;:a N;//!ba;s/\n//g' test
```

If the line doesn't end with an `"` get and join all the lines till the closing one (the line who ending with an `"`). Print all the others lines.

---

The same in standard `awk` :

```
awk '/^"/ && !/"$/ {ORS = ""} /"$/ {ORS = "\n"} 1' test
```

Or (standard `awk` too) :

```
awk '{ ORS = ((/^"/ && !/"$/) || (/^[^"]/ && !/"$/)) ? "" : "\n" } 1' test
```

Answer (score 1):

`GNU sed`

For lines with unbalanced quotes, keep appending a next line (`N`) at a time until they balance. At which point the newlines are removed

For already balanced lines, the removal is harmless since no newline is oresent in pattern space.

Assuming the last line can't have a hanging open quote.

```bsh
sed -E '
  /^(([^"]*"){2})*$/!{
    N;H;z;x;D
  }
  s/\n//g
' infile.csv
```

---

Same thing in POSIXly-sed

```bsh
sed -e ':a
  /^\(\([^"]*"\)\{2\}\)*$/! {
    N
    b a
  }
  s/\n//g
' infile.csv
```

---

Answer (score 1):

If your file was output from a MS tool like Excel then chances are the real line endings are `\r\n` and the newlines mid-field are just `\n`s and then all you need is the following, using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\r\n' '{gsub(/\n/,"")}1' file
"64f94e8e-4bd2-4721-95e7-7151cfbf3eb6"|"fanel"|""|""|""|"2020-05-20 12:23:54.611000+00:00"
"d955466b-125d-42dd-a1f6-a31e1ff6889b"|"Rancher_rke_1_0_8_Linux"|""|""|"Rancher 13 images scan:199M May 20 12:58 calico-cni.tar54M May 20 12:58 calico-kube-controllers.tar252M May 20 12:58 calico-node.tar108M May 20 12:58 calico-pod2daemon-flexvol.tar40M May 20 12:58 cluster-proportional-autoscaler.tar40M May 20 12:58 coredns-coredns.tar82M May 20 12:58 coreos-etcd.tar1.5G May 20 12:58 hyperkube.tar40M May 20 12:58 metrics-server.tar5.0M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend.tar488M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller.tar737K May 20 12:58 pause.tar129M May 20 12:58 rke-tools.tar"|"2020-05-20 09:56:43.388000+00:00"
"853f2f8b-563b-4ea3-a465-7be4510ce66f"|"SPOT_NEWSCAN_747"|""|""|""|"2020-06-09 08:11:02.563000+00:00"
"f3d735a7-7883-48c1-91cc-28075d300d62"|"kinesis-stream-manager"|""|""|""|"2020-05-21 06:50:15.440000+00:00"
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat -Ev file
"64f94e8e-4bd2-4721-95e7-7151cfbf3eb6"|"fanel"|""|""|""|"2020-05-20 12:23:54.611000+00:00"^M$
"d955466b-125d-42dd-a1f6-a31e1ff6889b"|"Rancher_rke_1_0_8_Linux"|""|""|"Rancher 13 images scan:$
199M May 20 12:58 calico-cni.tar$
54M May 20 12:58 calico-kube-controllers.tar$
252M May 20 12:58 calico-node.tar$
108M May 20 12:58 calico-pod2daemon-flexvol.tar$
40M May 20 12:58 cluster-proportional-autoscaler.tar$
40M May 20 12:58 coredns-coredns.tar$
82M May 20 12:58 coreos-etcd.tar$
1.5G May 20 12:58 hyperkube.tar$
40M May 20 12:58 metrics-server.tar$
5.0M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend.tar$
488M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller.tar$
737K May 20 12:58 pause.tar$
129M May 20 12:58 rke-tools.tar$
"|"2020-05-20 09:56:43.388000+00:00"^M$
"853f2f8b-563b-4ea3-a465-7be4510ce66f"|"SPOT_NEWSCAN_747"|""|""|""|"2020-06-09 08:11:02.563000+00:00"^M$
"f3d735a7-7883-48c1-91cc-28075d300d62"|"kinesis-stream-manager"|""|""|""|"2020-05-21 06:50:15.440000+00:00"^M$
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Remove any newlines that don't immediately follow a `"` doublequote:*

```perl
raku -ne 'if .match(/ <-["]>$ /) {print $_~"; " } else {print $_~"\n" };'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne '.match(/ <-["]>$ /) ?? ($_~"; ").print !! ($_~"\n").print;'
```

Answers above are coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Like other answers already posted, the issue seems to be that the OP's `csv` file contains embedded newlines. The code above detects and removes these newlines.

Sample Output:

```
"64f94e8e-4bd2-4721-95e7-7151cfbf3eb6"|"fanel"|""|""|""|"2020-05-20 12:23:54.611000+00:00"
"d955466b-125d-42dd-a1f6-a31e1ff6889b"|"Rancher_rke_1_0_8_Linux"|""|""|"Rancher 13 images scan:; 199M May 20 12:58 calico-cni.tar; 54M May 20 12:58 calico-kube-controllers.tar; 252M May 20 12:58 calico-node.tar; 108M May 20 12:58 calico-pod2daemon-flexvol.tar; 40M May 20 12:58 cluster-proportional-autoscaler.tar; 40M May 20 12:58 coredns-coredns.tar; 82M May 20 12:58 coreos-etcd.tar; 1.5G May 20 12:58 hyperkube.tar; 40M May 20 12:58 metrics-server.tar; 5.0M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend.tar; 488M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller.tar; 737K May 20 12:58 pause.tar; 129M May 20 12:58 rke-tools.tar; "|"2020-05-20 09:56:43.388000+00:00"
"853f2f8b-563b-4ea3-a465-7be4510ce66f"|"SPOT_NEWSCAN_747"|""|""|""|"2020-06-09 08:11:02.563000+00:00"
"f3d735a7-7883-48c1-91cc-28075d300d62"|"kinesis-stream-manager"|""|""|""|"2020-05-21 06:50:15.440000+00:00"
```

More generally, it might be concluded that the Sample Input provided by the OP is an odd `csv` wherein `|` stands-in for the `,` comma. It's not entirely clear how many columns each 'row' of the `csv` file contains otherwise. What you really need is a `csv`-parser!

Happily, you can parse the given Sample Input using Raku's `Text::CSV` module, making sure to set the `sep => "|"` parameter. (Also, be sure to provide a filename and/or path using the `in => PROJECT2.csv` parameter):

```perl
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @csv = csv(in => "PROJECT2.csv", sep => "|"); .raku.say for @csv;'
```

Sample Output (2):

```
$["64f94e8e-4bd2-4721-95e7-7151cfbf3eb6", "fanel", "", "", "", "2020-05-20 12:23:54.611000+00:00"]
$["d955466b-125d-42dd-a1f6-a31e1ff6889b", "Rancher_rke_1_0_8_Linux", "", "", "Rancher 13 images scan:\n199M May 20 12:58 calico-cni.tar\n54M May 20 12:58 calico-kube-controllers.tar\n252M May 20 12:58 calico-node.tar\n108M May 20 12:58 calico-pod2daemon-flexvol.tar\n40M May 20 12:58 cluster-proportional-autoscaler.tar\n40M May 20 12:58 coredns-coredns.tar\n82M May 20 12:58 coreos-etcd.tar\n1.5G May 20 12:58 hyperkube.tar\n40M May 20 12:58 metrics-server.tar\n5.0M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend.tar\n488M May 20 12:58 nginx-ingress-controller.tar\n737K May 20 12:58 pause.tar\n129M May 20 12:58 rke-tools.tar\n", "2020-05-20 09:56:43.388000+00:00"]
$["853f2f8b-563b-4ea3-a465-7be4510ce66f", "SPOT_NEWSCAN_747", "", "", "", "2020-06-09 08:11:02.563000+00:00"]
$["f3d735a7-7883-48c1-91cc-28075d300d62", "kinesis-stream-manager", "", "", "", "2020-05-21 06:50:15.440000+00:00"]
```

Why go to all this trouble? Well, once you have your `csv` file accurately parsed by a `csv`-parser, you can simply output rows or columns at your discretion. Example, changing the second statement above to `.[0].raku.say for @csv;` will output just the first column:

Sample Output (3);

```
"64f94e8e-4bd2-4721-95e7-7151cfbf3eb6"
"d955466b-125d-42dd-a1f6-a31e1ff6889b"
"853f2f8b-563b-4ea3-a465-7be4510ce66f"
"f3d735a7-7883-48c1-91cc-28075d300d62"
```

https://modules.raku.org/dist/Text::CSV:cpan:HMBRAND
https://github.com/Tux/CSV
https://raku.org